# Google Beacons Dashboard not showing any registered beacons

Tags: ios, estimote, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

I recently started to work with the Google Beacons Platform. I use Estimote Beacons, which I configured to use Eddystone UID as primary packet type. I walked through the following steps:

1) I created a new Google API Project and activated the Google Proximity Beacon API.

2) I downloaded the Beacon Tools iOS App, choose the previously created Google API Project and registered two of my Estimote Beacons. These beacons appear in the "Registered" tab of the Beacon Tools iOS App.

3) I went to https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/ and selected my Google API Project. The dashboard opens the project but it does not show any of my registered beacons. I just says "Loading...". I have authorized the Beacon Dashboard with the correct user.

Did I do something wrong? What else do I have to do to let my registered beacons appear in the Beacon Dashboard?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now my registered beacons appear in the Google Beacons Dashboard. I didn't do anything in the meantime. So I'm guessing it just takes Google a couple of hours (24+) to initially sync the data.

Now that my beacons appear in the Dashboard every change I make with the Beacon Tools iOS App immediately appear in the Dashboard.

Comment: I had several issues using the Google Beacons Dashboard with the Google Chrome Browser. Unfortunately I still have to use Safari or Firefox...